# What is the general solution of the one-dimensional time-independent Schrodinger's equation with constant potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

As I tried to learn quantum mechanics I have found two solutions of one-dimensional time-independent Schrödinger equation  with constant potential in various resources.

One is,$$\psi(x) = A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)\\\text{where}, k = \frac{2π\sqrt{2m(E-U_0)}}{h}\\ \text{In this case, probability density: }P_1(x) = \psi(x)\cdot\psi^*(x) = |\psi(x)|^2\\$$
And another is,
$$\psi(x) = Ce^{k'x} + De^{-k'x}\\\text{where}, k' = \frac{2π\sqrt{2m(U_0-E)}}{h}\\ \text{In this case, probability density: } P_2(x)=\psi(x)\cdot\psi^*(x)=|\psi(x)|^2$$
In both cases,

$A,B,C,D$ are arbitrary constants

$\psi(x) = $ The probability function of a particle

$\psi^*(x) = $ The conjugative function of $\psi(x)$

$m$ = the mass of the particle

$E$ = The total Energy of the particle

$U_0 =$ The potential energy of the particle

Now my question is, does $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ mean the same thing? If yes, then how?
And if not, then which is actually the general solution of time independent Schrödinger's equation?

$$\\$$
[**Edit**: *As far as I understood **these two solutions are not same.** (ie, if I put $C = 2$ and $D=3$ in the second solution, no value of $A\;and\;B$ can equalize these two solutions. Also if I put $A=2\;and\;B=3$ in the first solution no value of $C$ and $D$ can equalize them) So neither of them seems to be a general solution of TISE. Is there any mistake in this example? Or is there no general solution of TISE?*]

Comment: Is really the second form as you wrote? Isn't there an imaginary unit in the exponential arguments?

Comment: @GiorgioP You know most of the time potential energy is less than total energy. So there is an imaginary unit hidden in k'.

Comment: Now I understand. But this implies that the squared modulus should appear also in the first case.

Comment: @GiorgioP Why? As I have understood (*there might be lackings in my understanding*) in the first case **k** is used instead of **k'** (Actually **k' = ik**). And the value of **k** is not imaginary or complex for most of the cases. So there should no need of modulus in the first case.

Comment: *for most of the cases* means for the values of *x* such that $E>U_0$. And what about the points such that $E<U_0$? So in general the solution will have a piecewise purely real or purely imaginary ${\bf k}$. The squared modulus is in order.

Comment: Actually, the squared modulus could be eliminated in both cases. But, to explain why, I should write a complete answer and I am not sure I have time today.

Comment: @GiorgioP oh... Now I have understood. I missed the point that for $U_0 > E\;$  k can be imaginary. OK I am editing that. But still I have not understood which is the actual solution of TISE.

Comment: The TISE is a second order ODE and its solutions thus form a two-dimensional vector space. This means $P_1$ is the most general solution. $P_2$ is the same solution just with a relabelling of the parameters, $k^\prime = ik$, $C+D = A$ and $i(C-D) = B$. The only reason to use both is if you have a piecewise potential where one $U_0$ is different from the other $U_0$.

Comment: Check this out:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513474/why-do-we-pick-trigonometric-solutions-instead-of-complex-exponentials-when-so/513484

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i \sin{x}$ (which is known as [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)), both of your solutions are indeed the same, despite being written in different notations.

Notice, however, that what is meant by "Schrödinger equation" usually involves specifying a particular potential $V(x)$, and different choices of potential will, quite naturally, lead to different solutions. In this sense, your solutions are not general (but they do correspond to the same choice of potential, which I'm guessing to be $V(x) = U_0$).

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are the same. And not just the Probability density, but the entire wavefunction of a Quantum system is unique.

I think, you are missing the point that the coefficients can be imaginary. I will answer the question you asked in 'Edit part'.

> if I put C=2 and D=3 in the second solution, no value of A and B can equalize these two solutions.

$A = 5$ and $B = -i$

Like @Gandalf73 also answered, after applying the Boundary Condition, both $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ will turn out to be same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both are the solutions to the TISE and $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ will be same after applying the boundary conditions. Roughly speaking, and without going into too much details: the Schroedinger equation (or any other differential equation) has an infinite number of solutions. The system “chooses” the one specific solution according to the boundary conditions.

You can look at it this way: the system defines all possible wave functions. When a wave enters it in a specific way, it gets to be one of the solutions according to its behaviour as it entered the system. (Yes, I know it is not accurate to say the least, but it’s a convenient way to get your head around it).

And if you are looking at solutions for a scattered state, you don't deal with probability densities actually, but the probability current and the coefficient of reflection and transmission.

Comment: Then what are the boundary conditions of this equation? Does **boundary conditions depends on systems**? Or there is any **general boundary condition for Schoedinger's equation**?

Comment: As you said *both are the solutions to the TISE and P1(x) and P2(x) will be same after applying the boundary conditions* How it can Be? Say for example, I have choosen two arbitrary values for C and D as C = 2 and D = 3. **Now no real values of *A* and *B* can equalize *P1(x)* and *P2(x)***. so how can P1(x) and P2(x) be same?

Comment: @DipankarMitra why should A and B be real-valued?

Comment: @J.Murray I am not sure A and B real-valued or not. Can A and B take complex values?

Comment: @DipankarMitra Yes. Wavefunctions are generally complex valued, which shouldn’t be surprising because the two complex exponentials are also solutions.

Comment: @J.Murray oh..I have understood. But can C and D in the second solution take complex values as A and B?

Comment: @DipankarMitra Yes.

Comment: Boundary conditions are unique for a specific problem, you can't change. There are no general B.C. for SE but there are the wavefunction like the wavefunction has to continuous everywhere. My advice is solve a simple problem using both the solutions and apply appropriate B.C. and check if its true. Look how the wave is propagating.